# Longest subArray with no more than two distinct values that differ by no more than 1

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of integers what is the length of the longest subArray containing no more than two distinct values such that the distinct values differ by no more than 1

For Example:

arr = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3] -> length = 4;  [1,2,1,2]

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> length = 2;  [1,2]

arr = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2] -> length = 4;  [3,3,2,2]

I have such code

```
 public static int longestSubarray(List<Integer> arr) {
        int max = 0;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        while (i < arr.size() - 1) {
            set.add(arr.get(i));
            while (j < arr.size() && Math.abs(arr.get(i) - arr.get(j)) < 2) {
                if (!set.contains(arr.get(j))) {
                    if (set.size() == 2) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        set.add(arr.get(j));
                    }
                }
                ++j;
            }
            max = Math.max(max, j - i);
            j = ++i + 1;
            set.clear();
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Can there be a better solution?

Comment: In case of test case `[1, 295331535]` the output will be `0` however expected is `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Here's a dynamic program with `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space. The idea is that we can get the answer for the sequence ending at `A[i]` by looking at the best sequence ending at `A[i-1]` that possibly included higher elements, and the best sequence ending at `A[i-1]` that possibly included lower elements.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A){
  if (A.length < 2)
    return A.length;
    
  let best = 1;
  let bestLower = 1;
  let bestHigher = 1;
  
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    if (A[i] == A[i-1]){
      bestLower = bestLower + 1;
      bestHigher = bestHigher + 1;
    
    } else if (A[i] - 1 == A[i-1]){
      bestLower = 1 + bestHigher;
      bestHigher = 1;
    
    } else if (A[i] + 1 == A[i-1]){
      bestHigher = 1 + bestLower;
      bestLower = 1;
    
    } else {
      bestLower = 1;
      bestHigher = 1;
    }

    best = Math.max(best, bestLower, bestHigher);
  }
  
  return best;
}

arrays = [
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], // length = 4; [1,2,1,2]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // length = 2; [1,2]
  [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2] // length = 4; [3,3,2,2]
];

for (let arr of arrays){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  console.log(f(arr));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, only one question why we after changing the left and right borders still initialize units ie: after bestLower = 1 + bestHigher  we did  bestHigher = 1 and respectively bestHigher = 1 + bestLower we did  bestLower = 1? If I understand correctly this is unnecessary correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @IgorPereverzev it is necessary. `bestHigher` and `bestLower` are calculated to represent the longest sequence ending at `A[i]` that include either higher or lower elements (than `A[i]`), respectively. If `A[i] > A[i-1]`, `bestHigher` cannot be greater than 1 for the sequence ending at `A[i]` because we are not allowed to include `A[i-1]` in that sequence because the element is lower. (And vice versa if `A[i] < A[i-1]`.)

Comment: Can it not be a simple state machine which works on two variables, either their state can be none of the variables filled, first variable filled, both filled. (and checks to transittion state at any point between these states). But your approach looks better and efficient

Answer (score 4):

C# code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> arr = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3};
        List<int> set = new List<int>(); 
        int n = arr.Count;
        int max = 1;
        int i,j;
        for(i=0 ; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            set.Add(arr[i]);
            for(j=i+1; j<n; )
            {
                if(Math.Abs(arr[i]-arr[j])<2)
                {
                    if(!set.Contains(arr[j]))
                    {
                        if(set.Count == 2)
                        break;
                        else
                        set.Add(arr[j]);
                    }  
                }
                else
                break;
            j++;
            }
            max = Math.Max(max,j-i);
            set.Clear();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(max); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this problem, took some help from your code and implemented the same in C#. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain why you use the List<int> set? I particularly don't understand why you break when set.Count reaches 2.

Answer (score 1):

refer to this GFG Post
and there replace X by 1

Link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-subarray-in-which-absolute-difference-between-any-two-element-is-not-greater-than-x/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -3):

Java solution with O(n) time complexity

static int solution(List arr) {

```
    int subArrStart = 0;
    int changedSubArrStart = 0;

    int longSubArrayLen = 0;
    int currSubArrayLen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

        if (arr.get(subArrStart) == arr.get(i)) {
            currSubArrayLen++;
        } else if (Math.abs(arr.get(subArrStart) - arr.get(i)) == 1) {
            if (subArrStart == changedSubArrStart) {
                changedSubArrStart = i;
            }
            currSubArrayLen++;
        } else if (Math.abs(arr.get(changedSubArrStart) - arr.get(i)) == 1) {
            subArrStart = changedSubArrStart;
            currSubArrayLen = i - subArrStart + 1;
        } else {
            subArrStart = i;
            changedSubArrStart = i;
            currSubArrayLen = 1;
        }

        longSubArrayLen = Math.max(longSubArrayLen, currSubArrayLen);
    }
    return longSubArrayLen;
}
```